# Parsing a CSV file in C

Tags: c, csv, cgi

I have the following code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int lendata;
    printf("Content-type:text/html\n\n");
    printf("<html><body>");
    lendata = atoi(getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH"));
    char *buf = malloc(lendata+1);
    int i=0;
    char *data;
    while((data=fgets(buf,lendata+1,stdin)) != NULL){
        char *lines[i];     
        lines[i] = strdup(data);
        printf("%s<br>",lines[i]);      
        i++;

}
    printf("%d, %d",lendata,i); 
    free(buf);
    printf("</body></html>");
    return 0;

}
```

I am trying to parse a *.csv file with different data types inside (i.e. character strings, intger ). How can I process each line in the file? Thanks!

Comment: correct the #include#include#include line!

Comment: How would I then go about it?

Comment: strdup() allocates a new string each time.  You'd have to free those eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will be better....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int lendata;
    printf("Content-type:text/html\n\n");
    printf("<html><body>");
    lendata = atoi(getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH"));
    char *buf = malloc(lendata+1);
    int i=0;
    char *data;
    while((data=fgets(buf,lendata+1,stdin)) != NULL){
          /*char *lines[i]; */       
          /* lines[i] = strdup(data); */  
          printf("%s<br>",data);        
          i++;  
    }
    printf("%d, %d",lendata,i); 
    free(buf);
    printf("</body></html>");
    return 0;

}
```

sscanf call returns number of entries that were matched.

```
numentries = sscanf(line,"%s,%s,%s,%s,%s",ent1,ent2,ent3,ent4,ent5);
```

Comment: How can I then parse the content of the file?

Comment: Can I use sscanf to since the data inside the file are not numbers or integers?

Comment: Yes.  Just be careful of spaces, if there are any.  You might have to account fro them in the sscanf format.

Comment: first, check the man pages for the read line call. you split the input based on comma. In a pinch: read a line, while(c[I]++ != ',';

Comment: @JKTA Everything you need to know about `sscanf()` for this (and frankly the rest of the C standard library) can be found [at this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: @JKTA sscanf(line,"%s, %s,%s");  /* space after first comma, no space after second */